# How to create one DLL for all Windows 10 64-bit systems?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, g++

I recently created a DLL written in C++ using g++. The intent was to call it from a LabVIEW-built EXE, and this worked just fine. I then copied the LabVIEW EXE and its support code (including the DLL) over to a new PC (which was already pre-installed with the necessary LabVIEW support). On the new PC, the LabVIEW EXE could not load the DLL. I rebuilt the DLL on the new PC, replaced the old DLL, and then the LabVIEW EXE could load the DLL and run just fine again.

My questions are: Why did I need to rebuild the DLL on the new PC? Is it because of different hardware? How do I create one DLL for all Windows 10 64-bit systems?

Some information about the setup:

- Both PCs are running Windows 10 64-bit
- The DLL is basic and only uses the `<math.h>` and `<iostream>` libraries
- PC 1 is a DELL XPS
- PC 2 is an Intel NUC
- LabVIEW EXE built in LabVIEW 2021 64-bit
- LabVIEW 2021 64-bit runtime is installed on both PCs
- DLL built for 64-bit

I understand that sometimes a DLL built in Visual Studio requires a C++ Redistributable Package, but I haven't been able to find a reference to a redistributable for g++. Is that what I need?

I am relatively new to C++, so perhaps I am just not searching for the right things.

Comment: Sounds like the DLL is not compiled as a standalone executable, and thus has its own dependencies on other DLLs that would have to be deployed to every PC. When the DLL fails to load, are you getting an error code explaining why?

Comment: Run [`ntldd -R my_prog.exe`](https://github.com/LRN/ntldd) to get a list of DLLs your program needs. Copy the ones in the compiler's `bin` directory next to your exe, and ignore the rest.

Comment: "Both PCs are running **Windows 10** 64-bit" doesn't matter nearly as much as whether you are using **LabVIEW** 32-bit or 64-bit, since 64-bit Windows machines are perfectly capable of running 32-bit applications that use 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: Unfortunately LabVIEW just errors with "Failed to load". But that does make sense; I didn't realize I had to explicitly compile the DLL as standalone. Searching on making DLLs standalone, it looks like I probably need "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread" added to my g++ command. I'll try that.

Comment: @Ben Voigt I am running LabVIEW 2021 64-bit runtime on both PCs, with the EXE compiled in LabVIEW 2021 64-bit.  I will add that to the setup info.

Comment: You can use Dependency Walker to check for dependent DLLs

Comment: Simply rebuilding your DLL wouldn't install missing dependencies though.  This really feels like a 32/64 bit mismatch.

Comment: After adding "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread" to my g++ command and rebuilding the DLL on my XPS, I replaced the DLL on the NUC with the new one. The EXE ran properly this way as well. So I think @Remy Lebeau was correct. The DLL needed to be built as a standalone DLL.